# How to get selected object value from selection event from customized pop-up menu extension?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, popup

I have added "Demo" as my customized pop-up menu in eclipse view and I used "viewercontribution" for same. My pop-up menu visibility on type of "x" object only, then how can get the value of "x" object in my action class?

Comment: The `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point is deprecated and has been for a long time. New code should be using `org.eclipse.ui.menus`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the view defines a selection provider you can get the active selection with

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

ISelection selection = page.getSelection();

if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
    Object selected = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();

    ... cast selected to your object type
}
```

Also the `selectionChanged` method of your `IViewActionDelegate` will be called for each change to the selection.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply